# "error": "Server error: You must call `@jwt_required()` or `verify_jwt_in_request()` before using this method",

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-decorators

I have a flask backend that makes calls to our MongoDB database and I intend to use `decorators` to check for a **particular token** before any financial transactions are allowed. This token is placed in the request header of every such API call.

I am using flask resources to manage the endpoints.

Here is the resource class:

```
class FlutterUserFundingWallet(Resource, Starter):
    """
    Flutter class to handle wallet transactions
    """

    method_decorators = {
        'post': [jwt_required(), check_client_header, app_block_status(get_jwt_identity), requires_authorization_token],
        'get': [jwt_required(), check_client_header, app_block_status(get_jwt_identity)]
    }

    def post(self):
        try:
            .....
```

Now this is the code for the `decorator`:

```
def requires_authorization_token(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            auth_token = request.headers.get("authorization-token")
            if not auth_token:
                return jsonify({"message": "Authorization token is missing"}), 401

            # Call the confirm_authorization function to validate the token
            authorized, message, status = confirm_authorization(auth_token)

            if authorized:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                # return jsonify({"message": message}), status
                response = jsonify({"success": False, "error": message, "data": None})
                response.status_code = status
                return response

        except Exception as e:
            response = jsonify({"success": False, "error": f"Server error: {str(e)}", "data": None})
            response.status_code = 403
            return response

    return wrapper
```

And this is the code for the `confirm_authorization` being called in the decorator:

```
def confirm_authorization(auth_token: str) -> tuple:
    """
    Function to confirm cash transactions for user
    :param auth_token: string
    :return: tuple
    """
    try:
        current_app.logger.info('confirm_authorization function called ...')
        # Search for auth token
        db.transaction_tokens.create_index('id')
        result = decode_auth_token2(auth_token)
        print(f'payload: {result}')
        if result[0]:
            hashed_token = db.transaction_tokens.find({'id': str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, result[1]['token']))})
            if hashed_token is not None and result[1]['sub'] == str(get_jwt_identity()):
                # Delete the expired token
                remove = db.transaction_tokens.find_one_and_delete(
                    {'id': str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, result[1]['token']))}
                )
                if remove is None:
                    current_app.logger.info("Stored token not deleted!")
                return True, "Approved", 200
            else:
                return False, "Server error", 500
        else:
            return result[0], result[1], result[2]
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(f'confirm_authorization function error: {e}')
        return False, f"Server error: {e}", 500
```